# Can a Blazor (.net 7) WASM (Client & Server APIs) be deployed to an Application under IIS (Not in the root of the site)

Tags: iis, deployment, blazor

I'm having a difficult time determining if its possible to deploy a .net 7 Blazor WebAssembly (Full Client and Server projects) to an application under IIS.   I can easily deploy it to the root of a new IIS site, but I need to deploy it to an Application under an existing IIS Web site.

For example https://example.com/Application

I can't find any example of how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Right-click on the Web Site, select "Add application" option.

"Alias" the name given in this field will be used in the URL to access this child application
"Physical Path" location application source code
[image]

Click ok then child application is created in the iis server, you can access this "Application" application as `https://example.com/Application`.